# Dynamic Nested Forms in Rails 4 + Ruby 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms, dynamic, nested

I have a link which brings me a modal window.

Example:

```
link_to "@#{client_name(i)}", 
account_client_path(current_account.id,i.client_id), 
:remote => true,
class: "client-link", 
"data-toggle" => "modal", "data-target" => "client-dialog-form"
```

Inside this window I want to have a form for this model called `Issue`:

```
class Issue < ActiveRecord::Base

  before_save { self.number = number.downcase }

  validate :number,          presence: true, 
                             uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false },
                             length: { maximum: 50 }

  has_many :items
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :items

end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :issue
end
```

My problem is, I want my `Issue` to have dynamic generated nested items subforms. What's the best way to do it? I've googled and searched a lot in here, but with no success.

Answer (score 0):

**Link**

You can clean up your link code like this:

```
link_to "@#{client_name(i)}", account_client_path(current_account.id,i.client_id), :remote => true, class: "client-link", data: {toggle: "modal", target: "client-dialog-form"}
```

---

**Form**

If you're loading nested form fields, there are several things you have to do to get it to work:

1. Build the ActiveRecord objects
2. Use `fields_for` to load the objects
3. Handle the form params on submit

Here's how:

```
#app/controllers/issues_controller.rb
def new
    @issues = Issue.new
    @issues.items.build # Creates AR object
end

def create
    @issues = Issue.new(issue_params)
    @issues.save
end

private

def issue_params
    params.require(:issue).permit(:your, :issue, :params, items_attributes: [])
end

#app/views/issues/form.html.erb
<%= form_for @issue do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :info %>
    <%= f.fields_for :items do |i| %>
        <%= i.text_field :info %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

This will allow you to call the form & append it to your page. Because of your English (which is good), I couldn't determine if you wanted to add extra fields on the fly. If you want to do that, I'll have to write some more answer for you!

Let me know in the comments!

Comment: Thank you, Rich. Yes, i do want to add extra fields on the fly via ajax or some gem. i've found so far a gem called cocoon ( https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon ).

Comment: Hi Rich, would you mind instructing me on how to add extra fields on the fly? In this scenario, a link which retrieves the html for an `item` (single text_field named info)?